# What is the name of the B2C authentication flow used in Desktop applications?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

In the following official Microsoft B2C example, a desktop application uses B2C to authenticate users and get an API access token for a user:

[WPF application signing in users with Azure Active Directory B2C and calling an API](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-desktop)

I like to take a look at the protocol diagram and the HTTP calls used in the authentication flow.

What is the name of the B2C authentication flow used in the example?

Considering that a WPF desktop application does not have a callback url, where can I find the sample/documentation for the HTTP calls between B2C and the application?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#mobile-and-native-applications), it uses the OAuth 2.0 [authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow) flow.

The redirect URI is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-native-application?tabs=app-reg-ga).

Comment: Thank you for help. How the redirect URL "com.onmicrosoft.contosob2c.exampleapp://oauth/redirect" redirects to a wpf or desktop app? a wpf app is not a web server. I have this question since a few years. Appreciate if you can demystify the url question.

Comment: Yeah, good question! Maybe @JasSuri can help?

Comment: Native apps (mobile/desktop) can register callback URIs with the OS.